# How do I change an email subject and other properties with an Outlook Web add-in?

Tags: outlook, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to change the email subject with an Outlook Web add-in?  What about email category or other properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change the subject using the [Subject.setAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn482531.aspx) method. See [Mailbox API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn705877.aspx) for more information about APIs.

Also you may find the [Understanding the JavaScript API for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160953.aspx) section helpful.